# is there a way to add LinkedIn insights code so it gets properly triggered in Vue

Tags: vue.js, linkedin-api

is there a way to add LinkedIn insights code so it gets properly triggered in a Vue project? or does adding the code before the closing body tag suffice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include LinkedIn insights code into the whole app then use it in the **main.js** file. Else you can use where you want for specific pages.

Below is the example code that you can use and it will work.

```
(function () {
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    var b = document.createElement("script");
    b.type = "text/javascript";
    b.async = true;
    b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);
  })();
  window._linkedin_partner_id = "0000000"; //paste your id here
  window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
  window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(window._linkedin_partner_id);
```

Comment: I have tried the above code logic in my footer file in a NextJS project. It doesn't work. It gives an error when you hover over, ``` _linkedin_partner_id ``` It gives a popup message stating: "Property '_linkedin_partner_id' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'."

Comment: can you try without "window" . Actual implementation is without "window".
```
window._linkedin_partner_id
```
is same as
```
_linkedin_partner_id
```
it just depends on the framework requirement.

Comment: Also, you can see NextJS requirements for that purpose to handle DOM "window"

Comment: So the issue is that NextJS is SSR so I have to use the useEffect hook.
So just removing ``` window. ``` from the code will fix it?
My current code looks like this:
Check the next comment

Comment: useEffect(()=>{
const script = document.createElement("script");
(function(){
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
var b = document.createElement("script");
document.body.appendChild(script);
b.type = "text/javascript";
b.async = true;
b.src = "https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js";
s.parentNode.insertBefore(b, s);
})();
window._linkedin_partner_id = "clients ID"; //paste your id here
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids = window._linkedin_data_partner_ids || [];
window._linkedin_data_partner_ids.push(window._linkedin_partner_id);
    })

Comment: I don't know about the `useEffect` but you can test by removing `window.`